# Sinatra fails to render view on first load

Tags: sinatra, haml, rack, webrick, tilt

I'm getting the following error the first time I try to access the localhost route in the browser.

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/admin/Workspace/site/(__TEMPLATE__).haml
```

After refreshing, it works fine until I restart the server.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems like the __TEMPLATE__ variable gets set on the first load and that is why it won't work. Please post your main code also.

Comment: Can you please post the file structure of your application?

Comment: I guess we need the code to debug this issue.